# How to create multi-polygon intersecting a circle / necklace using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Imagine a necklace with beads. I need a d3 solution that can help be draw this. 
We had used, Combinatorial Necklaces and Bracelet: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html 
But we want to extend it. So I looked some more, and found Circle Polygon Intersection http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4218871

However, I don't know if Circle Polygon Intersection is the best approach. I am looking for suggestions and solutions in d3.js that can help solve the problem.

The number of beads / polygon can be in 100s or 1000s and of different colors.

Comment: There isn't a d3 layout to do this, but you should be able to figure it out if you sit down with pencil and paper and an old trigonometry text-book to figure out what the positions of the circles will be for a given number of nodes in your circle.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550)?

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for your reply. I just updated the question with the rough image of what I am looking for.

Comment: Amelia, that is true, but I am looking for a generic function as the number of points that I need to show on the circle can be in 100s...and of diff colors

Comment: Sumi, write a few cases and then try to abstract it.

Comment: Luxelin, can you please elaborate? Did you mean in reference to the D3 code? I am looking for an extension of http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4218871

Comment: You've really confused me with that second example, I don't see how it's related except that it has both nodes and a circle!  As for my original comment, I wasn't suggesting you hard-code positions, but rather figure out a function.  I.e., if you have `n` nodes, the angles between them will be `2*Math.PI/n`, then the angle of node `i` relative to a start vector from the center of your circle will be `i*2*Math.PI/n`.  Then you need to [convert from polar coordinates to Cartesian](http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html) to get (x,y) values.

Comment: :) humm... Thanks Amelia. Let me start again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your question is related to display neckelaces with d3. If so, here's my solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqoqMj

```
function necklace (svg, radius, len) {
  // unit conversion
  var degrees = (pos) => pos * 360 / len
  var radians = (pos) => degrees(pos) * Math.PI / 180

  svg.append('svg:circle')
  .attr('r', radius).attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)

  // add circles (data is 0...len)
  svg.selectAll('.circles')
  .data(d3.range(0, len)).enter()
  .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .attr('cx', (pos) => radius * Math.cos(radians(pos)))
    .attr('cy', (pos) => radius * Math.sin(radians(pos)))
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
}

function svg (w, h) {
  return d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .append('svg:g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + w / 2 + ',' + h / 2 + ')')
}

// create a necklace from a d3 svg object
necklace(svg(250, 250), 100, 16)
```